# What should/could I feed my outdoor rabbits in winter?

Tags: diet, rabbits, outdoor, winter

My rabbits live in Middle Europe outside in my garden the whole year.
What should I regard in choosing their diet during winter?

(Picture of my male exploring the big white play ground:)
[image]

Comment: What I found myself until now: dried leafs from autumn, bamboo (not the lucky one, the one from the garden) and cabbage instead of salad (stands frost better)